# MATLAB MEX Program optimization sliding window function

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, mex, sliding-window

I implemented a mex function that creates a 3D sliding window (`hxwxd`) and this window slides a 3D image (`MxNxP`), pixel by pixel. It works but it's not as fast as I expected. I compared the execution time (test image of `32x32x32` and sliding window of `3x3x3`) of the mex function with the same function but developed in standard MATLAB and the result was exactly the opposite of what I thought.

```
function .mex ~= 28 s
function .m   ~= 24 s
```

I used the MSVC compiler and I compiled the mex file with these options:

```
mex -v -COPTIMFLAGS='-O3 -DNDEBUG' slidingWindow3D.cpp
```

So what I thought is that probably I don't have implemented the function in the best way. This is the mex function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"       

using namespace std;

void createSubWindow(mxArray *subWindow, 
                     const double *image, 
                     const double *borders, 
                     const mwSize *imageDimensions,
                     const double windowSize,
                     int ii, int jj, int kk)
{
    const unsigned int p_lowerBound = ii - (int) borders[0];
    const unsigned int n_lowerBound = jj - (int) borders[1];
    const unsigned int n_upperBound = jj + (int) borders[1];
    const unsigned int m_lowerBound = kk - (int) borders[2];
    const unsigned int m_upperBound = kk + (int) borders[2];
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    for(int m = m_lowerBound; m <= m_upperBound; ++m)
    {
        for(int n = n_lowerBound; n <= n_upperBound; ++n)
        {
            memcpy(mxGetPr(subWindow)+counter, &image[p_lowerBound+ imageDimensions[0]*(n + imageDimensions[1]*m)], sizeof(double)*windowSize);
            counter += (unsigned int) windowSize; 
        }
    }

}

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    #define O_IMAGE       plhs[0]
    #define I_IMAGE       prhs[0]
    #define I_WINDOWSIZE  prhs[1]
    #define I_FUN         prhs[2]
    #define I_OPTIONS     prhs[3]

  // Argument Checking:
  if(nrhs < 1 || nrhs > 4) /* Check the number of arguments */
    mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of input arguments.");
  else if(nlhs > 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");

  // Variable declarations
  const mwSize *dim, *originalDim;
  mwSize ndim, *dimSubWindow;
  double windowSize, *pad, *output_image;
  mxArray *imagePad, *padding, *windowShape, *mask, *subWindow, *temp, *inputFun[4], *inputPadFun[3];

  /*Get dimensions of input image*/
  ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(I_IMAGE);
  originalDim = mxGetDimensions(I_IMAGE);

  // Get windowSize value
  windowSize = *mxGetPr(I_WINDOWSIZE);

  // Padding input matrix
  pad = (double *) mxCalloc(ndim, sizeof(double));
  for(int i = 0; i < ndim; ++i) 
  {
      pad[i] = floor(windowSize/2);
  }
  padding = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(ndim,1,mxREAL);
  memcpy(mxGetPr(padding), pad, sizeof(double)*ndim*1);
  inputPadFun[0] = const_cast<mxArray *>(I_IMAGE);
  inputPadFun[1] = const_cast<mxArray *>(padding);
  inputPadFun[2] = mxCreateString("symmetric");
  mexCallMATLAB(1, &imagePad, 3, inputPadFun, "padarray");

  /*Get dimensions of padded image*/
  dim = mxGetDimensions(imagePad);

  //Options structure fields
  windowShape = mxGetField(I_OPTIONS,0,"windowShape");
  mask = mxGetField(I_OPTIONS,0,"mask");

  // Create mxArray * subWindow
  dimSubWindow = (mwSize *) mxCalloc(ndim,sizeof(mwSize));
  for(int i = 0; i < ndim; ++i) 
  {
      dimSubWindow[i] = windowSize;
  }
  subWindow = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim,dimSubWindow,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);

  // Prepare input for feval function
  inputFun[0] = const_cast<mxArray *>(I_FUN);
  inputFun[2] = const_cast<mxArray *>(windowShape);
  inputFun[3] = const_cast<mxArray *>(mask);

  O_IMAGE = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim,originalDim,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
  output_image = mxGetPr(O_IMAGE);

  // Slide subWindow on the padded image
  for(int i = pad[0]; i < dim[0]-pad[0]; ++i)
  {
      for(int j = pad[1]; j < dim[1]-pad[1]; ++j)
      {
          for(int k = pad[2]; k < dim[2]-pad[2]; ++k)
          {
              // function to create the subWindow
              createSubWindow(subWindow,mxGetPr(imagePad),pad,dim,windowSize,i,j,k);
              inputFun[1] = const_cast<mxArray *>(subWindow);
              mexCallMATLAB(1, &temp, 4, inputFun, "feval");              
              output_image[(i-(int)pad[0])+originalDim[0]*((j-(int)pad[1])+originalDim[1]*(k-(int)pad[2]))] = *mxGetPr(temp);
          }
      }
  }

  // Clean UP
  mxFree(pad);
  mxDestroyArray(padding);
  mxDestroyArray(inputPadFun[2]);
  mxDestroyArray(subWindow);
  mxDestroyArray(imagePad);
}
```

And here the .m function that does the same thing:

```
function [ o_image ] = SlidingWindow( i_image, i_padSize, i_fun, i_options )%, i_windowShape, i_mask )
%SLIDINGWINDOW Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

o_image = zeros(size(i_image,1),size(i_image,2),size(i_image,3));
i_image = padarray(i_image,i_padSize,'symmetric');
i_padSize = num2cell(i_padSize);
[m,n,p] = deal(i_padSize{:});
[row,col,depth] = size(i_image);
for i = m+1:row-m
    for j = n+1:col-n
        for h = p+1:depth-p
            ii = i-m;
            jj = j-n;
            hh = h-p;
            temp = i_image(i-m:i+m,j-n:j+n, h-p:h+p);
            o_image(ii,jj,hh) = feval(i_fun, temp, i_options.windowShape, i_options.mask);
        end
    end
end

end
```

Do you have any ideas why the .mex function is slower than the .m function? Do you think that there is a better way to implement the sliding window in mex? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are going about convolution all wrong.  What is wrong with using `convn` directly?  In just your .m code, I don't see the point of actually extracting the window from the 3D image when you can operate on it directly.  This is unnecessary memory copy (the corresponding `memcpy` in your C code that does this is not needed).  In addition, you should never expect performance gains with MEX files that just call `mexCallMATLAB`.  Why should this be faster?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can't use the simple convolution because what I have to do inside the sliding window is a non linear function. It's something like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297554/matlab-circular-sliding-window-and-pixel-values-on-diameters-extraction) but in 3D, thus instead of having a circle mask, I have a spherical mask. I don't know, why it should be faster, I thought so.

Comment: Rule of thumb is that always loop through the first dimension in the inner-most loop. You loop through 0th dimension in the outer-most loop, then cache efficiency would usually be bad. However, using a 3D window will cause bad cache efficiency anyway.

Comment: @BugsFree Since you say you want non-linear filtering, they you are right that `convn` won't cut it.  But what I said about avoiding copies and not expecting gains using `mexCallMATLAB` both apply.  Also, @user3528438 is right about loop order.  Read down, then across, then remaining dimensions.  Hardware caching is more likely with contiguous memory read between iterations.